# ¿Cómo hago para que Grep indique el número de línea?

Tags: grep

¿Cómo encontrar palabras dentro de archivos desde un directorio mostrando la línea en la que se encuentre?

Básicamente es tan simple como eso

```
grep -r -i 'código' ./
```

Lo que quiero ahora es que me muestre la línea en la que se encuentra el código en común.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente usa `-n` para que Grep indique el número de línea:

```
grep -n "patrón" ficheros*
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero
hola que tal
yo muy bien
adios pues
$ grep -n 'muy bien' fichero
2:yo muy bien
```

Comment: gracias!, la próxima me fijo con más atencion en el man.